# code igniter and exec?

Tags: php, codeigniter, background

I have a script that, inserts into the database e.g. 20,000 users with email addresses in batches of 1000

(so two tables, emailParent, emailChild), there are 1000 rows in emailChild for every row in emailParent.

I want to run a script that sends these emails which basically says
`//check_for_pending_parent_rows() returns the id of the first pending row found, or 0`
`while($parentId = check_for_pending_parent_row()){//loop over children of parent row}`

Now because this is talking to the sendgrid servers this can take some time.

So I want to be able to hit a page and have that page launch a background process which sends the emails to sendgrid.

I thought I could use `exec()` but then I realized, I am using code igniter, which means the entry point MUST be `index.php` hence, I don't think `exec()` will work,

How can I launch a background process that uses code igniter?

Comment: You can do this by taking parts of `index.php` as well as `system/codeigniter/CodeIgniter.php` and constructing a script that does basic CI initialization.  It's not pretty -- the code I'm looking at does this with about 70 lines of (formatted, commented) PHP.  I don't have permission to share the code I'm looking at, but it references a more robust solution for a similar problem: http://www.foostack.com/foostack/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exec` to run a vanilla CLI PHP script to calls the page via `cURL`

See http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php for info on cURL

This is what I have had to do with some of my codeigniter applications

(Also make sure you set time out to 0)

And doing it this way, you are still able to debug it in the browser

Answer (score 2):

**This is not really an answer, Just something that is too long to post as a comment**

> @Frank Farmer: 70 lines seems a bit
>   excessive, this example from simple
>   test does it in pretty much half that,
>   What is the difference?

```
<?php
//---------------------------
//define required constants
//---------------------------

define('ROOT', dirname(__file__) . '/');
define('APPLICATION', ROOT . 'application/');
define('APPINDEX', ROOT . 'index.php');

//---------------------------
//check if required paths are valid
//---------------------------
$global_array = array(
    "ROOT" => ROOT,
    "APPLICATION" => APPLICATION,
    "APPINDEX" => APPINDEX);

foreach ($global_array as $global_name => $dir_check):
    if (!file_exists($dir_check)) {
        echo "Cannot Find " . $global_name . " File / Directory: " . $dir_check;
        exit;
    }
endforeach;

//---------------------------
//load in code igniter
//---------------------------
//Capture CodeIgniter output, discard and load system into $ci variable
ob_start();
include (APPINDEX);
$ci = &get_instance();
ob_end_clean();

//do stuff here
```

Answer (score 1):

Petah suggested cURL, but recently (since 2.0), **CodeIgniter now permits calls to your controllers through the [CLI](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html)**:

This should be easier than cURL.